# Organizing a lot of shortcuts on the desktop for quick access, transmissions

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-explorer

I'm in transmission business and have to have fast access to a lot of places on the network, over 100.  So I setup folders with related shortcuts on the desktop and setup explorer to 'open each folder in its own window’.  Which worked like a charm in XP and Server 2003.  There is a FOLDER button on the tool bar which I flip if navigation pane is needed and it stops opening folders in a new window and acts like normal explorer, while my other folders are sitting in their individual windows and most important, remember their settings.  Well, that was then.

Now we upgraded to server 2008 and win 7 and this setup is not working.  The original folders with shortcuts do not remember their settings and have navigation pane, so I have to scroll or reset every time I open them.  If I turn off navigation pane in the shortcut folders, then Explorer does not have it, but if I turn it on, the folders are screwed up.  If I set 'open in it's own window', the Explorer with navigation pane is opening in multitude, which it never done before.

Are there any suggestions how to setup quick access to many places in organized way?  I would really appreciate it.
Alla

Answer (score 1):

A couple of suggestions:

1- [PS Hot Launch VVL](http://www.pssoftlab.com/pshl_info.phtml) - This is what I use to keep track of groups of network locations.  I have a hotkey set to <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (above tab) to open the menu where my mouse currently is.  Very handy. **I'm in no way associated with whoever makes this program*

2- Create a new toolbar on the task bar to link to a folder somewhere on your machine(or network) that has shortcuts to each of your locations inside it, then you can just click the double arrows on the explorer bar to see all the shortcuts.  Being shortcuts, you can rename them creatively to have them higher or lower on the list, using #s or an '_' for example.

[image]

3- Use the favorites (sounds like you already shot this option down) list on the left side of the explorer window you mentioned.  I don't know of a way to group those, but it's easy to browse to the folder level above where you want to open, and drag the desired folder into the favorites list.  I tried this before using PS Hot Launch

Comment: Thank you much for a quick reply.  #1 - cannot do, corporate computer.  #2 - use already, but it is not comfortable, each transfer has 3 or 4 folders (orig, arch, ack...), I keep shortcuts in a folder in a sort of matrix, the shortcuts are numbered and named to properly sort and take their place.  The problem is that every time I open the folder it needs to be reset, sorted, etc.  I already use restored Quick Access tool bar (first thing I did) for other shortcuts and those folders. It is not moveable as before, sorry to say.

Comment: #3, takes too much room in the navigation pane and does not solve the problem.
My main issue is ‘remembering folder settings’, which is crystallizing as my main problem, I begin to see now.
Thank you,

Comment: On the bit about having to reset folders, sort them, etc, every time you open it, is that a product of each folder having a different way it needs to be sorted and changing it in one folder uses that setting each new time you open?  Or are they all sorted one way and that way just isn't being remembered on new windows?

Comment: Yes to the last one, they are all med-small icons, by name, align to the grid, and I size the window so it is as many icons across as there applications there: 4 to 6, they number+named for quick access.  Basically, I want 3.1 window idea.  I'm not old fashioned, but this is just practical for me.  Network is huge and the naming for dir's is a mile long (SAN, NAS environments, etc). Scrolling is not an option.

Comment: Then I would need to open those shortcuts in separate windows so I can see more then one (up to 10 sometimes) to check on file movements, to compare contents, etc. I need small independent windows to remote directories.

Comment: I'm not finding much help. You can go to any folders' properties->Customize tab and specify one of the five default folder types to optimize view & sort settings, but I couldn't make any of those consistently act like what I think you're wanting. And since it's a corporate computer, other suggestions like Explorer++ are out, so I'm stuck

Comment: I was customizing the default folder types wrong. Correct way = http://goo.gl/7lsY -- If you can narrow down the folder settings you commonly use for the various folders into a couple of groups, you could leave the "General" folder type settings alone so your normal windows explorer experience is the same as always, but any folders set to use the other default folder types could be customized to display and sort the items differently based on the folder type you choose.

Comment: Great! I think I will go this way.  Thanks a lot of advice.  I tried to customize folders but did not go all the way.